# Select and count attribute for non-unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of persons and activities - neither column is unique.
I need to rank every user by the count of distinct activities, e.g.:

```
_________________ 
|PERSON|ACTIVITY|
-----------------
|Lars  | Sleep  |
|James | Eat    |
|Lars  | Sleep  | 
|Lars  | Sleep  | 
|Kirk  | Shred  |
|James | Shred  |
-----------------
```

Lars appears thrice, but performs the same activity repeatedly.
Kirk appears once, so he is identical to Lars in number of activities.
James performs two distinct activities, so he should be ranked the highest.

The expected output:

```
James - 2
Kirk - 1 
Lars - 1
```

(ordering of identical counts is irrelevant)

The solution I have come up with involves applying DISTINCT to the person column and iterating over the names, selecting the activities for each and applying DISTINCT followed by COUNT. It feels like there must be a better way.

Comment: Take a look at GROUP BY .

Comment: You should include the query that you attempted.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want `count(distinct)`:

```
select person, count(distinct activity) as num_activities
from t
group by person
order by num_activities desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use GROUP BY function. 
SELECT PERSON, COUNT(DISTINCT ACTIVITY) AS count FROM YOUR TABLE GROUP BY PERSON ORDER BY count;

Comment: Where is activity in the query ?

Comment: Highlight your query and select ctrl-K , Most people prefer script to be readable

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Person, COUNT(DISTINCT Activity) AS ActivityCount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Person
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```